# Xamarin/Visual Studio 2015: Custom Proguard configuration

Tags: configuration, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, proguard

I need to make a customized Proguard configuration. However I cannot find out how to do that. When building a new configuration file is copied into the */obj/release/proguard* folder. How can this configuration file be customized?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Just put your `Proguard.cfg` into your Project
2. Right click on `Proguard.cfg` > "Build Action" > "ProguardConfiguration"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is 100% correct on how to add the file.
To make sure you file gets picked up you can check the output logs, it will contain something like this:

```
ProguardConfigurationFiles:
      {sdk.dir}tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt;
      {intermediate.common.xamarin};
      {intermediate.references};
      {intermediate.application};
         Proguard.cfg;
```

**NOTE:** Make sure that you set your MSBuild output verbosity to Detailed for this (Tools > Options > Build and Run)